# Blinking control object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to make an object to start/stop blinking (with fadeIn() and fadeOut() for an object in jquery.
I already have a method blink() that makes the element blink once, and it works, but I'm trying to make it blink again as callback to the fadeOut() and don't seem to be able to make it without getting a stack overflow. This is what I've got so far:

```
     Indicator = function(str) {
        this.el= $(str);    
        this.blink = function(){ 
            var callback = function() { 
                                return function(){
                                    console.log(this.el)
                                    this.blink();
                                }.apply(this);
                                //if (!this.stopped)
                                    //this.blink();
                            }.apply(this);


            this.el.fadeIn(200).delay(200).fadeOut(200,callback);
            }
            this.stopped = false;
            this.stop = function() { this.stopped = true; }
    }

    function start(){
       indicator =new Indicator('#indicator p');
       indicator.blink();
    }
```

(I know my apply()'s are a mess, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

You have created explicit endless recursion. You are calling `blink` that calls `fadeOut` that calls `callback` that calls `blink`. I would suggest you rewrite this function with setInterval, something like:

```
this.fadeDuration = 200;
this.blinkIntervalRef = null;
this.blink = function(){
    this.blinkIntervalRef = setInterval(
         function(){this.doBlink();},
         this.fadeDuration*3
    );
}
this.stop = function() {clearInterval(this.blinkIntervalRef );}
this.doBlink = function(){
    //this is just shortcut, not to make horizontal scroll
    var interval = this.blinkIntervalRef; 
    this.el.fadeIn(interval).delay(interval).fadeOut(interval);
}
```

Note that it is not tested, but at least it will give you a direction.

**Update:** here's working example, but requires some debugging and time-spans adjustment:

```
Indicator = function(str) {
    this.el= $(str);    
    this.fadeDuration = 100;
    this.blinkIntervalRef = null;
    this.doBlink = function(){
        //this is just shortcut, not to make horizontal scroll
        var interval = this.blinkIntervalRef; 
        this.el.fadeIn(interval).delay(interval).fadeOut(interval);
    }
    this.blink = function(){
        var ctx = this;
        this.blinkIntervalRef = setInterval(function(){ctx.doBlink();},this.fadeDuration*4);
    }
    this.stop = function() {clearInterval(this.blinkIntervalRef);}
}

function start(){
   indicator = new Indicator('#indicator p');
   indicator.blink();
}

$(document).ready(function(){start();});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying not to use a setInterval because I wanted to see how I could use it (for a different related problem). I see you solved the "calling the this object from within the interval" a better way.

Comment: By the way: this is inherently recursive, right? there's no way to make a new call to the same thing as a callback to it without recursion

Answer (score 0):

this is what i once used to do similar kind of thing:

```
function initializeBlink()
{      
        $('#indicator p').fadeToggle('slow', fadeToggleBlinker);
}

function fadeToggleBlinker()
{      
        var timeout = 2000;
        if(this.style.display == 'none')
                timeout = 1000;
        var tmp = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function(){tmp.fadeToggle('slow', fadeToggleBlinker)}, timeout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar but with an object, with start() and stop() methods that stopped the interval (and some meddling with the scope)